# cv2.fillPoly receives list of polygons, only filling last polygon

Tags: python, opencv

Something is off. [fillPoly documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/4.5.3/d6/d6e/group__imgproc__draw.html#ga311160e71d37e3b795324d097cb3a7dc) says "Fills the area bounded by one or more polygons." and "**pts** Array of polygons where each polygon is represented as an array of points."

But the following code is drawing all 5 polygons, and filling the bottom which is not one of the polygons at all!

Is this me? Or is it a bug?

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from numpy import int32, array
img = np.zeros((720, 1280))
pnts = [array([[242, 387], [122, 478], [144, 228], [246, 139], [242, 387]], dtype=int32),  # top
        array([[242, 387], [511, 585], [460, 377], [246, 139], [242, 387]], dtype=int32),  # front
        array([[242, 387], [511, 585], [390, 633], [122, 478], [242, 387]], dtype=int32),  # left side
        array([[246, 139], [460, 377], [360, 427], [144, 228], [246, 139]], dtype=int32),  # right side
        array([[144, 228], [360, 427], [390, 633], [122, 478], [144, 228]], dtype=int32)]  # back  
cv2.fillPoly(img, pnts, color=[255,255,255])
cv2.imshow("img", img)
cv2.waitKey()
```

[image]

**Workaround:**

```
for polygon in pnts:
    cv2.fillPoly(img, [polygon], color=[255,255,255])
```

Comment: Looks like cv2 is using the "even-odd rule" for polygon filling, which means that overlapping areas effectively cancel each other out.  The area that gets drawn isn't actually the nonexistent bottom face, it's simply the portions of the front and side faces that do not overlap any other faces, and therefore don't get cancelled.